# Clean memory being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, memory, optimization

I have used memory stream to download the file. As soon as file get downloaded I need to clear up all memory being used by that memory stream.

```
context.Response.BufferOutput = true;
//DecryptAndStoreInMemory decrypt a requested file and store in memory
using (MemoryStream ms = DecryptAndStoreInMemory(context.Server.MapPath(path), userFileName))
    {
      byte[] bytesInStream = ms.ToArray();
      context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
      context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytesInStream.Length.ToString());
      context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + userFileName);
      ClearStream(ms);
      context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesInStream);
      context.Response.Flush();
      context.Response.Close();
      Array.Clear(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
    }


ClearStream(MemoryStream stream)
{
    if(stream != null)
    {
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

//Decrypt a file and store in memory stream.

```
public MemoryStream DecryptAndStoreInMemory(string inputFilePath, string userFileName)
{
    MemoryStream msOutput = null;
    if (File.Exists(inputFilePath))
    {
        try
        {
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_password, _salt);
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (msOutput = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            int data;
                            while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                            {
                                msOutput.WriteByte((byte)data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return msOutput;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException)
        {
            throw new Exception("Sorry we can not serve " + userFileName + " file at this time.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Sorry we could not locate " + userFileName);
    }

}
```

After file is sent to response it doesn't free up the memory being taken. It almost took twice the size of file. 17 MB file takes almost 40 MB memory.

What should be done to free up those space.
I tried to clear byte array but found that it only replaces each element of array with 0 keeps its length same.

Comment: The first line of defense is the garbage collector. If the variable `bytesInStream` isn't referenced anywhere anymore it should be collected and the memory freed. That also assumes that `bytesInStream` is the actual troublemaker. Can you try and insert `GC.Collect();` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();`? During memory profiling, does the memory consumption get better when you wait a little bit?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt
I did write GC.Collect() at the top and at the bottom which results in memory clean up in next request for the same file. 

If I request same file again then it frees up memory used previously and again reserve memory

Answer (score 2):

To avoid double-buffering, *don't call `.ToArray()`*; instead, you can access the existing  buffer via `ms.GetBuffer()`. Note that  this is oversized, so you presumably need to use:

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Length);
```

Note that  you cannot deterministically tell an array to go away, and `Array.Clear` does not have the effect you want. Cleanup is the job of the garbage collector, which you shouldn't usually mess with.

---

However! A better approach is to *not read everything  in one go at all*, but rather: to use a pure streaming approach. I don't know how your  `DecryptAndStoreInMemory` is implemented, so I cannot tell whether that  is possible  in your case, but: it usually is.

Comment: I have edited my question and have added  `DecryptAndStoreInMemory`
method please have a look and let us know about any future enhancement.

Comment: and regarding above 
`context.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.Length);`

I am not getting `BinaryWrite` method with 3 input parameters. I have just one that takes `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET framwerk you don't have direct control over memory usage. Your memory is controlled by the garbage collector (GC). When you have disposed your stream and it finally becomes dereferenced, it is called *dead*. That means it is up for garbage collection, which will automatically occur when memory pressure becomes too high.

In the vast majority of the cases there is no need for any optimization here, because just because memory is used, it does not mean that it can not be freed up during garbage collection. Managed memory with a GC is also not necessary slower than unmanaged memory, because allocation of new objects is fast in managed memory as compared to unmanaged memory (if there is enough memory available), because managed memory is unfragmented.

You can initate garbage collection with `GC.Collect()`, but that could make your code *less* performant than running garbage collection automatically. And initiating a collection would not necessarily decrease your used memory size, because the GC does not always return freed memory to the OS.

Comment: Thank you for information. Though .NET framework does free up memory automatically I am in trouble regarding performance of other application hosted in server. 

I came to know my above logic is the main culprit for that and I need to fix that thing any how.